# How to remove the echo in this PHP code?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP Code

```
#The facebook message
$fh = fopen('comments.txt', 'r') or die('Unable to open data1.txt');
while($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '||' )) {
   if ($line[0] == $name) {
       echo <<<EOL
My color is $line[2]
EOL;
       break; // if there's only ever one '5678' line in the, get out now.
   }
}
fclose($fh);
$fb = $line[2];
```

I would like to remove the echo i.e. remove the "My color is...." on the user's browser please. How can I remove the code without getting any errors please?

I tried many times... I am still a beginner to PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you just remove that code?

Comment: If you are using some source control software (if not, you should), you can simply delete the lines. If you ever need them back, you can browse through the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// echo <<<EOL
// My color is $line[2]
// EOL;
```

You can comment out code like that.

Comment: It gave me the following error...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/galawe/public_html/magimagi.com/login/uploader.php on line 58

Comment: You commented all three lines yes?

Comment: My guess is that you are very new to coding. You might do well to go through a tutorial on the basics of coding, there are many tutorials available online or you could go out and get a book that might your coding much good.

Comment: Lastly, if a question is answered correctly, it is common courtesy to Accept the answer. If you ask too many questions and never accept the answers, it will be shown on your ID when you ask and people will generally not answer them too much.

Comment: I am very brand new to PHP coding... what books do you suggest please for beginners and self-study? Thank you once again.

Comment: You might do well to read through a few net based guides first. This one doesn't seem too bad at all: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_To_Programming and you can go on from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any treatments in the `if` statement, you can comment the whole block :

```
#The facebook message
$fh = fopen('comments.txt', 'r') or die('Unable to open data1.txt');
while($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '||' )) {
   if ($line[0] == $name) {
       /*
       echo <<<EOL
       My color is $line[2]
       EOL;
       */
       break; // if there's only ever one '5678' line in the, get out now.
   }
}
fclose($fh);
$fb = $line[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can comment out or delete the following code:

```
/*echo <<<EOL
My color is $line[2]
EOL;*/
```